# Where's the build_type configured in React Native Sentry

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, sentry

I'm using the [Sentry SDK for React Native](https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry). In every report I can find a parameter **Build Type** in the App section. Unfortunately the value is either `simulator` or `test`. I'd expect something like `release` in my released application.

Does anyone know where this parameter is configured for an iOS application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parameter will be set automatically from `KSCrash`
It's `app store` for apps that have a receipt,
it's `test` for ad hoc builds, and `simulator` for yeah you guessed it, simulator builds xD
There is also `debug` for builds directly on the device.

see:
https://github.com/kstenerud/KSCrash/blob/64229cfa482d135c109dc3c66db7b30d1da855fc/Source/KSCrash/Recording/Monitors/KSCrashMonitor_System.m#L454-L473

Comment: OK, so the reason why we don't have `app store` is that we're not yet in the store but using TestFlight only. Thanks a lot!